# C++ template inheritance issue with base types

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following code and it fails to compile

```
template < typename T >
class Base
{
public:

    typedef T * TPtr;

    void func()
    {
    }
};

template < typename T >
class Derived : public Base< T >
{
public:
    using Base< T >::TPtr;
    using Base< T >::func;

    TPtr ptr;
};

int main( int c, char *v[] )
{
    Derived< int > d;
    d.func();
}
```

The compiler issues the following.

```
t.cpp:16: error: 'TPtr' does not name a type
t.cpp:16: note: (perhaps 'typename Base<T>::TPtr' was intended)
```

Now I know I could simply do as the compiler is suggesting but I can't understand why the

```
    using Base< T >::TPtr;
```

doesn't work.

If I comment out the "`TPtr ptr`" line then it compiles, proving that the "`using Base< T >::func;`" statement works.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think `using Base<T>::func;` does what you think it does,  `d.func()` works normally because it is inherited from the parent class.   Is there a reason you cannot do `typedef Base<T>::TPtr TPtr`?

Comment: I'd have to use "typedef typename Base< T >::TPtr TPtr" but as I commented to Konrad, yes, this works but it kind of defeats the purpose of inheritance if I have to define new types based on base class ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Base< T >::TPtr` is a so-called *dependent name* so you need to prefix it with `typename` to make the declaration work.

Additionally, `using` doesn’t work with `typename` so you need to use a `typedef` instead:

```
typedef typename Base<T>::TPtr TPtr;
```

The issue is that the compiler can’t decide – without knowing what `T` is! – whether `TPtr` in this context names a type or a variable/function. To avoid ambiguities, it always assumes the latter, unless explicitly told otherwise (hence the need for `typename`).

Comment: I tried "typename TPtr ptr;" and this still failed. "expected nested-name-specifier before TPtr"

Comment: @Scary: my mistake. Updated the answer, try again now.

Comment: Yes, I agree this works. However, It kind of defeats the purpose of inheritance if I have to define a new type based on the base type.

Comment: +1: thank you Konrad, it been a long time I wished I knew and understood that point before. Now clearly stated and explained by you. I'll use it as soon as I can.

Comment: I think a more appropriate name is 'dependent name' instead of 'dependent type'.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of a defect. While C++03 *did* provide `using typename`, it did *not* provide the necessary rules to say that the name declared by the using declaration is a type-name. It just provided the instrument to say that the name referenced in the using declaration is a type-name. So you *can* do in fact the following, but with varying success among compilers. Some will make it work, but some won't.

```
template < typename T >
class Derived : public Base< T >
{
public:
    using typename Base< T >::TPtr;
    using Base< T >::func;
      // up to here it's alright
    TPtr ptr;
      // but this may only work on some compilers
};
```

[This issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#11) has been fixed for C++0x. For C++03, the way to work around it is to use a `typedef` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand why the:
>      using Base< T >::TPtr;
>   doesn't work.

Due to possible template specialization, `Base< T >::TPtr` can be anything: a type name, variable name, function, etc.

With the keyword `typename` you tell compiler that it can be a type name only.

[Here is a decent explanation](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html) of what sort of ambiguities it serves to resolve. Scroll down to "The Problem", it covers your case precisely.

Answer (score 0):

When you write
    TPtr ptr;

it is seen as `Base<T>::TPtr` and the compiler will assume that this is a member variable  of `Base<T>` or a method of `Base<T>` (this is what it will do because `Base<T>::TPtr` is a 'dependant name' and unfortunately in this case the compiler will assume variable or function instead of type) thus making the declaration invalid.

The keyword `typename` allow the compiler to know explicitly that `TPtr` names a type.

Comment: No, that’s wrong: the compiler won’t assume that it’s `static` – in fact, the same declaration works fine for `func` which isn’t `static` either.

Comment: See comment above. I tried using "typename TPtr ptr;" and also tried "using typename Base<T>::TPtr" and they both failed.