# Function template specialization failure: coding error or MSVC2013 bug?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

The code below compiles correctly with g++ 4.8.1 (mingw), and a variety of recent clang and gcc versions on http://gcc.godbolt.org/, however with MSVC2013 Update 4 it fails, apparently due to the `typedef typename A<T>::value_type value_type;` line. The compiler gives the following error:

> x.cpp(30): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template '`void B<C,int>::bar(void)`'
>        With the following template arguments:
>        '`MemberFn=void C::baz(int)`'

The simpler typedef `typedef T value_type;` works.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a known bug in the Microsoft C++ compiler?

Supplementary question:

- From a stylistic point of view, assuming that I have the choice, would it be more idiomatic to redefine types in the derived class (e.g. `typedef T value_type;`) or to pull them in from the base class (e.g. `typedef typename A<T>::value_type value_type;`, or in C++11 `using typename A<T>::value_type;`)? (Note: I'm hedging on C++03 compatibility right now, hence the avoidance of `using`.) There was some inconclusive discussion here: [Use typedef/using from templated base class in derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816509/use-typedef-using-from-templated-base-class-in-derived-class) The reason I ask is that if `typedef T value_type;` is preferred anyway, I don't need to worry so much.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
struct A {
    typedef A<T> base_type;
    typedef T value_type;
};

template <typename Derived, typename T>
struct B : public A<T> {
    typedef Derived derived_type;
    //typedef T value_type; // this works
    typedef typename A<T>::value_type value_type; // this fails in MSVC 2013
    //using typename A<T>::value_type; // this fails in MSVC 2013 too

    template<void (derived_type::*MemberFn)(value_type) >
    void bar()
    {
        (static_cast<derived_type*>(this)->*MemberFn)(42);
    }
};

struct C : public B<C, int> {
    void baz(int i)
    {
        std::printf("baz(%d)\n", i);
    }

    void foo()
    {
        bar<&C::baz>();
    }
};

int main(int, char *[])
{
    C c;
    c.foo();
}
```

**Update #1:** This is a reduced test case from a framework. I am not asking for general critique of the structure. I do not expect the structure to make sense without context.

**Update #2:** Here is a related question discussing whether `using` is valid in combination with `typename`: [C++ template inheritance issue with base types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758656/c-template-inheritance-issue-with-base-types)

**Update #3:** I have filed a public bug report at Microsoft Connect. If you can reproduce the issue, and believe that it is a bug, please upvote the bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1740423

Comment: MVSC2014 doesnt exist, its either 2013 or 15, but if its update 4 its probably 13

Comment: `typedef typename A<T>::value_type value_type;` or any other version of this shouln't be required as `value_type` can be inherited from `A`

Comment: @Creris thanks. I've updated the title and question to MSVC2013.

Comment: @SimonKraemer `value_type` is a dependent type. It can't be used unqualified. you could (in theory) write: `typename A<T>::value_type` everywhere.

Comment: Yes, but you could do the same with `typename B<T, T>::value_type`. So what's your point?

Comment: @RossBencina Could you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve with this? It looks unnecessary complicated.

Comment: @SimonKraemer my point is that `value_type` is a dependent type and therefore is not directly inherited from `A` as you claim.

Comment: @RossBencina Where exactly is the problem if `A<T>::value_type` is the same as `B<Derived, T>::value_type` as long as T is the same.

Comment: @SimonKraemer aside from the error, no problem, just a question about style. (P.S. Will post a link to the full code in a few weeks, when it works.)

Comment: @RossBencina Ok. I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a possible solution (I can only test this with VS2015)

If you use the base type as a template parameter itself it is resolved and you can access the `value_type`.

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef A<T> base_type;
};

template <typename Derived, typename T, typename Base = A<T>>
struct B : public Base
{
    typedef Derived derived_type;
    typedef void (derived_type::*member_func_type)(typename Base::value_type);

    template<member_func_type MemberFn>
    void bar()
    {
        (static_cast<derived_type*>(this)->*MemberFn)(42);
    }
};


struct C : public B<C, int> 
{
    void baz(int i)
    {
        std::printf("baz(%d)\n", i);
    }

    void foo()
    {
        bar<&C::baz>();
    }
};
```

Or the solution I would prefer:

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    typedef A<T>    base_type;
    typedef T       value_type;
};

template <typename Derived, typename T, typename Base = A<T>>
struct B : public Base
{
    typedef Derived                     derived_type;
    typedef typename Base::base_type    base_type;
    typedef typename Base::value_type   value_type;

    typedef void (derived_type::*member_func_type)(value_type);

    template<member_func_type MemberFn>
    void bar()
    {
        (static_cast<derived_type*>(this)->*MemberFn)(42);
    }
};
```

I must admit that this solution has its flaws, like the ability to override the 3rd template parameter with something else. At least the other base class needs to have `base_type` and `value_type` declared.

---

**EDIT:**
Using a `static_assert` can prevent changing the `Base` template parameter.

```
template <typename Derived, typename T, typename Base = A<T> >
struct B : public Base
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<Base, typename A<T>>::value, "Redefinition of template parameter Base is not allowed");

    typedef Derived                     derived_type;
    typedef typename Base::base_type    base_type;
    typedef typename Base::value_type   value_type;

    typedef void (derived_type::*member_func_type)(value_type);

    template<member_func_type MemberFn>
    void bar()
    {
        (static_cast<derived_type*>(this)->*MemberFn)(42);
    }
};
```

Example:

```
template <typename T>
struct D {
    typedef D<T>    base_type;
    typedef T       value_type;
};

struct E : public B<C, int, D<int>>
{
};
```

Result:

```
error C2338: Redefinition of template parameter Base is not allowed
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Changing the order of the template parameters of `B` changes the behaviour. Here the original code with just the order of `T` and `Derived` changed.

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T>
struct A {
    typedef A<T> base_type;
    typedef T value_type;
};

template <typename T, typename Derived>
struct B : public A<T> {
    typedef Derived derived_type;
    //typedef T value_type; // this works
    typedef typename A<T>::value_type value_type; // this fails in MSVC 2013
                                                  //using typename A<T>::value_type; // this fails in MSVC 2013 too

    template<void (derived_type::*MemberFn)(value_type) >
    void bar()
    {
        (static_cast<derived_type*>(this)->*MemberFn)(42);
    }
};

struct C : public B<int, C> {
    void baz(int i)
    {
        std::printf("baz(%d)\n", i);
    }

    void foo()
    {
        bar<&C::baz>();
    }
};


int main(int, char *[])
{
    C c;
    c.foo();
}
```

This compiles and works fine.

I'm still not completely sure that this is a bug.

---

**Update**

So this seems to be a missing feature in MSVC. MSVC (up to 2015/14.0) doesn't seem to support "Two-phased-name-lookup".

> **Darran Rowe:** VC hasn't implemented three C++98/03 features: two-phase
>   name lookup, dynamic exception specifications, and export. Two-phase
>   name lookup remains unimplemented in 2015, but it's on the compiler
>   team's list of things to do, pending codebase modernization. Dynamic
>   exception specifications also remain unimplemented (VC gives
>   non-Standard semantics to throw() and ignores other forms), but they
>   were deprecated in C++11 and nobody cares about them now that we have
>   noexcept. It's unlikely that we'll ever implement them, and there's
>   even been talk of removing them from C++17. Finally, export was
>   removed in C++11.

Source [C++11/14/17 Features In VS 2015 RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/19/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rtm.aspx)

There has been a bug requesting that feature in 2012 but it was closed without a comment: [support two-phase name lookup - by Ivan Sorokin](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/742478/support-two-phase-name-lookup)

So it seems like you are doing everything right here, but MSVC just doesn't support this part of the C++ standard.

Comment: Thank you Simon. Very interesting that this works. It does compile in MSVC 2013. I had to change `>>` to `> >` to get clang and gcc to accept the examples. I like the `member_func_type` typedef -- didn't realise that would work inside a template arg list. Like you, I'm not sure whether the 3rd template argument is a feature or a wart.

Comment: @RossBencina I have updated my answer, so that `typename Base = A<T>` can't be changed externally.

Comment: If you add an answer to the main question: "Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a known bug in the Microsoft C++ compiler?", then I could accept this answer.

Comment: I wish I could. I just updated my answer as I found that the order of the template parameters has an effect.

Comment: Only thing I can think of:
`C` when used as the first template parameter isn't complete yet (`T=int` isn't yet set). So the declaration starts with something like `struct C : public B<incomplete type, int>`. So everything becomes incomplete at some time and is only resolved so much later that the compiler can't handle it.
Other compilers may use another method for type deduction and specialization and therefore work with this construct. Still it's only a guess...

Comment: Update: It's a missing feature in MSVC

Comment: I'm not sure that missing two-phase lookup is the *cause* of this issue. But there is definitely something fishy. Well done discovering that swapping the template parameter order "fixed" it. That is bizarre. Note that I have filed a bug with Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1740423

Answer (score 1):

Looks right. I tested it with VS2015, same error message. In fact, it should work without the typedef in B because it inherits the 'value_type' from A, so it's also in the namespace if struct B.

Comment: thanks for testing in VS2015. I don't think types can be inherited from dependent types without qualification though. Note that the base class `A<T>` depends on a type parameter to `B` (i.e. `B` is also a template).

Comment: I can't give you an ISO link atm, but when a class inherits from another, you have access to all defined names from the base class (with respect to public, proteced and private). Doesn't matter if it is an template or not. Seems the VS has a problem with your template member function with a method pointer as template argument (which isn't that trivial to parse for a compiler^^)

Comment: Maybe, but I don't think so: "the compiler does not look in dependent base classes when looking up nondependent names." https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members

Comment: In case you are interested, I put together a set of related declarations and tested them in MSVC and clang: https://gist.github.com/RossBencina/157eecf2189739cd913f